# jquery function to create buttons dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to see if possible if there is a way with jquery to create dynamic buttons. The buttons will be exactly the same but pass specific variables to functions that link to sites or create links to sites. I dont want to have to create each new list item if I have over 300 of them. Is there some way to create a function for each list item to create the buttons dynamically?

Here is the html

```
<nav id="menu">
    <div id="app">
<ul class="List"><li><span>Enter Number below</span>
            </li>
            <div id="number">
            <input type="text" name="number" id="textbox1" value="22984">
            </div>              
                <li><span>Disney</span>
                <ul id="programs">                  
                      <li><span>Lands</span>
                          <ul id="10min">

                             <li><span>Adventureland</span>
                                <ul id="Adventureland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                            <button class="redirect" id="AdventureLand">Open Website</button><br/>
                            <button class="txtLinky" id="Adventureland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                                <div id="linkified">value</div>     
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li><span>Frontierland</span>
                                <ul id="Frontierland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                   <button class="redirect" id="Frontierland">Open Website</button><br/>
                                     <button class="txtLinky" id="Frontierland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                            <div id="linkified">value</div> 
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li><span>Fantasyland</span>
                                <ul id="Fantasyland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                    <button class="redirect" id="FantasyLand">Open Website</button><br/>
                                    <button class="txtLinky" id="Fantasyland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                            <div id="linkified">value</div>     
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li><span>Tomorrowland</span>
                                <ul id="Tomorrowland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                    <button class="redirect" id="TomorrowLand">Open Website</button><br/>
                                    <button class="txtLinky" id="Tomorrowland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                            <div id="linkified">value</div>     
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                   </li>

                </ul>
            </li>               
        </ul>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$(".redirect").click(function(){                 
            goUrl = 'http://www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val();
            window.location = goUrl;
            });

$(".txtLinky").on("click", function () {    
            var link = 'Copy and paste '+ 'http://teambeachbody.com/shop/-/shopping/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val(); 
                $(this).parent().children('#linkified').html(link);

           $(this).parent().children('#linkified').linkify({
               tagName: 'a',
               target: '_blank',
               newLine: '\n'
            }); 

            $(this).parent().children('#linkified');
            });
```

here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VFhK9/18/

Comment: you're reusing ID's that's generally a bad idea. use classes instead

Comment: what ids are you referring to?

Comment: `ul` containing `div`s and `li`s? Just saying...

Comment: id=TomorrowLand, id=linkified, you are pritty much duplicating any id you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

First of all I would suggest to revise your HTML code cause having other tags except LI inside UL is a bad practice... also you are using not unique IDs for the different elements...

Ignoring all the issues withe HTML formatting, here is example that will go through all UL element with ids that ends with 'land' and add new LI element with two buttons inside:

```
$('ul[id$="land"]').each(function() {
    var ul = this;
    $(ul).append(
        $(document.createElement('li'))
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('button'))
                    .addClass('redirect')
                    .text('Open Website')
                    .click(function() {
                        var goUrl = 'http://www.example.com/' + $(ul).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val();
                        window.location = goUrl;
                    })
            )
            .append(
                $(document.createElement('button'))
                    .addClass('txtLinky')
                    .text('Click Link')
                    .click(function() {
                        // add other functionality here...
                    })
            )
    )
});
```

I think general idea is clear... just build HTML with minimum required information and use jQuery to add the rest dynamically.

Here is updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFhK9/20/).

Comment: while this kind of works, what if all the ul elements with ids are all unique. how can this be accomplished

Comment: when you build initial HTML mark the ULs that should be processed with some specific class - 'land' etc. and use $('ul.land') instead